# Proof by Contradiction - What are we negating exactly?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

When using proof by contradiction, we first find the negation of the statement and try to prove it false, I am assuming. However, I ran into a problem when testing this:
Suppose you want to prove $P \to Q$. When we take the negation of this statement, I first thought we take the negation of the *entire* implication, so we would be assuming $\lnot(P \to Q)$. I thought this would have been equivalent to saying $P \to \lnot Q$, the way it's supposed to be written, but they produce different truth tables. Why is it that we only negate the statement $Q$ and not the entire implication? Are we not trying to prove that the *implication* is true?

Comment: Recall that $P \to Q$ is equivalent to $\lnot P \lor Q$, so by De Morgan, $\lnot (P \to Q)$ is equivalent to $P \land \lnot Q$. With a proof by contradiction, we tend to assume not just the negation of the conclusion (i.e. assume $\lnot Q$), but also that the premises hold (i.e. assume $P$). Put those assumptions together? We assume $P \land \lnot Q$, i.e. $\lnot (P \to Q)$. It comes out the same either way.

Comment: Alternative perspective: $~[~P \implies Q~] \iff [ ~(\neg Q) \implies (\neg P) ~].$  So, you start with the assumption $(~\neg Q)~$ [i.e. that $~Q~$ is false], and then see if this implies that $~P~$ is false.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you that clears up my confusion. Turns out ¬(P→Q) _was_ the case and P→¬Q means something different, as it is not equivalent.
As a side note how do you format variables nicely with that font?

Comment: @PatrickHu You can find a reference for formatting in MathJax [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It's a lot like LaTeX, if you've used it. I also formatted your question with it, so you can press [edit] to see how I did that. You can also right-click over any mathematics, select menu "Show Math As $\to$ TeX Commands" to see the code that formats the formula.

Answer (score 1):

The negation of $P \to Q$ is $\lnot(P \to Q)$. However, this is not the same as $\ P \to \lnot Q.$

$P \to Q$ means whenever $P$ is true, $Q$ is true also.

Therefore, $\lnot(P \to Q)$ means that there is at least one case where $P$ is true but (i.e. and) $Q$ is not true.

Whereas $\ P \to \lnot Q$ means that every time $P$ is true, $Q$ is not true.

In general, it is clear that these two statements are not the same, and it is easy to come up with examples to illustrate this: I will leave this as an exercise.